# Why boost::qi rules' attributes must be declared with parenthesis?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I wonder why a `qi::rule` with an attribute must be declared like this:

```
qi::rule<string::iterator, std::string(), ascii:space_type>
```

And not like this

```
qi::rule<string::iterator, std::string, ascii:space_type>
```

Which would be more natural to me. I did not even know that the first form would be a valid template instantiation, and I still do not understand how it can be.

Can you explain that trick ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There’s no trick. The attribute type is *not* `std::string`. It’s a *function* which *returns* `std::string`. Because that’s essentially what a Qi rule is (if you squint hard enough): it’s a function which parses a piece of text and returns the parsed value.

These are just one possible attribute type. Other rules accept values, and consequently are functions which have a parameter:

```
qi::rule<string::iterator, void(std::string), ascii::space_type> end_tag;
```

This is an example from the [Qi documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi_and_karma.html#spirit.qi_and_karma.tutorials.mini_xml___asts_).